# Sync failed:-857 The remote database identified by remote ID '%1' is already synchronizing or the database connection is unusable:

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3, sup, mobilink

I am working with iOS native application in iOS using objective C and SUP as middleware .I am using the same provisioning profile for two fifferent application to run in iPAD.

My application was working well before . But now when I try to run it is showing an error like,
**The remote database identified by remote ID '%1' is already synchronizing or the database connection is unusable: unable to access the lock for that remote ID 
Error code  -10343**

What can I do to solve this?
when I searched in google I got some informations like

'The MobiLink server could not access the lock for the remote ID in the consolidated database or the MobiLink system database. The remote ID may have been locked by another synchronization, or the database connection may be unusable. Please check the database connection and try the synchronization later.

Please help me ...Thanks for any help in advance...
'

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the database is locked by some applications.